# Free/open Translation databases?

Tags: database, dictionary, translation

Are there any open/free downloadable translation databases, besides wiktionary?

(any language welcome)

Comment: I'm statistically cross-referencing wikipedia articles with the same title in different languages to make associations between words in one language and their counterpart in another.

It works quite well, but my validated base-vocabulary is too tiny.

Comment: @Quandary so did u find out the downloadable database? if so, can u share it here?

Comment: @lakesh: No. The best thing I could find was this
http://www.ttmem.com/terminology/download-translation-memory/ and this http://wiki.proz.com/wiki/index.php/Publicly_accessible_translation_memories_(TMs) ; But they're both bad.

Answer (score 3):

You could try contacting [IATE](http://iate.europa.eu/iatediff/about_IATE.html).
It's the European Union's database and it might be readily available. It being the EU you might have to wade through a couple of Red Seas of tape though :)

Another good source could be [Glosbe](http://glosbe.com/about), who are trying to build a large dict based on translation memories. According to their about section they allow downloads of the translation memories as well, so try contacting them.

Answer (score 3):

You can download in OmegaWiki. See: http://www.omegawiki.org/

> The aim of our project is to create a dictionary of all words of all
>   languages, including lexical, terminological and ontological
>   information. Our data is available in a relational database, as a
>   result it is possible to use the data for many purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Babel Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/babel/) it has a very interesting translation pack, if you need to translate you can also use [Google Translation FAmily](http://code.google.com/intl/es-419/apis/language/)

> Wondering what "have a nice day" looks
>   like written in Hindi? You can use
>   Google Transliterate to transform a
>   given written language into dozens of
>   other scripts.

Comment: I'm looking for a downloadable database. I already know Google translate, and I really need a database, not a web-service. I'm doing larger scale computations. A web-service totally kills performance. Plus I am looking for a dictionary, not a complete translation program.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one simple approach for quickly getting the translations you're looking for:

1. Get all the words & phrases you want into a text file, where each "translation target" is on a its own line
2. Use https://translate.google.com to simultaneously translate entire block for each language with 1 click
3. Copy/Paste results into spreadsheet, where each column can be for a different language translation

Comment: Interesting idea. Would this be legal? It's basically copying their database, and I'm not sure what it's licensed under but I assume it's not very free...

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://tatoeba.org/

It's a collaborative multi-lingual sentence translation database.